# CString as return value

Tags: c++, mfc

I wrote little wrapper for XML Lite library to use it in my MFC project. Can I use this code?

```
CString GetValue()
{
    const WCHAR* pwszValue = NULL;
    UINT cwchValue = 0;

    m_pReader->GetValue(&pwszValue, &cwchValue);

    return CString(pwszValue);
}
```

Or shoud I use CString& parameter in GetValue method signature?

Comment: Have you tested this? Well, the answer is yes, actually, but where do your doubts come from?

Comment: What is `m_pReader`? What error are you getting?

Comment: when it returns like this, will it call to the destructor of CString at the end of the method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're thinking about efficiency, then turn on optimization and **measure**. And consider whether the difference, if any, matters to you. It's almost sure that the compiler will do return value optimization (RVO) here.

But as a general rule, use the coding practice that gives you more *clear* code, i.e. in this case the function result, which gives more concise, robust and readable calling code.

That said, it looks like you're *leaking memory* for the `pwszValue`, and the Hungarian notation prefix is not exactly readable and reduces clarity, so the code needs a bit of reworking even when you do the sensible thing and use the function result value.

Comment: "it looks like you're leaking memory for the pwszValue" how come?

Comment: @Luchian: it *could* conceivably be that `m_pReader->GetValue` stores the address of a statically allocated string in `pwszValue`, but how likely is that.

Comment: Unfortunately it is extremely likely. [GetValue(WCHAR**, UINT*)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms752870(v=vs.85).aspx) doesn't get you a value, but sets the parameter to point to a string that will be changed almost immediately afterwards.

Answer (score 3):

There's no need to return through a parameter, this should work.

If you're worried about efficiency, don't. Return value optimization will most likely occur in this case.

Comment: Ehm, this is MSVC we're talking about here. Don't assume anything about optimisation. Test instead.

Comment: @MrLister: Yes, this is MSVC, there is no need to assume, it has been tested, it performs RVO.

Answer (score 0):

`CString&` would be dead wrong, returns a reference to a temporary, your program would crash very quickly.

Comment: The OP means a CString& as a function parameter. That will work.